# Using javascript change the angular formly template html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I have below code snip.

```
 page.fields[{
 template: '<div><img ng-click="exportCSV();"src="../Login/images/excel_icon.jpg" title="Export CSV"/></div>',
 controller: ['$scope', function (scope) {                                
      scope.exportCSV = function () {                                    
        var __this = this;
        this.fields[0].template = '<div>hello</div>';
        this.fields[0] = angular.copy(this.fields[0]);
```

after perform some action i want to change the template html inside this function.

```
function cb(status) {
   __this.fields[0].template = '<div>hello Ankur</div>';
   __this.fields[0] = angular.copy(__this.fields[3]);

 }]
```

it is not set the new template value but when i perform any action page then it reflect the change in template. please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand much. But this 2 strings looks like in wrong order

```
__this.fields[0].template = '<div>hello jiiii</div>';
__this.fields[0] = angular.copy(__this.fields[3]);
```

Comment: Actually it's angular-formaly control, in which i am using template to display download excel image. When click on that image it will take some time for that time i am just hide the excel image and display other image when download completed then display excel image. Problem is that excel image didn't display after download the file but when click on page then displayed.